# Execute command after \maketitle execution

Tags: titles

using a package I need to execute a command after the \maketitle command.
is there any way to do that? I'm searching for commands working like \AtBeginDocument.

I'm creating my LaTeX package and it would be good to have this feature.

---

I've tried this:

```
%copy content of \maketitle
\let\myMakeTitle\maketitle
%redefine \maketitle adding my commands
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\myMakeTitle\sbox0{$ $}\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0}
```

It works inside the document but it gets ignored if i put this code inside a package.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please tell something more about the problem? Stated this way is a bit too vague.

Comment: Sure, i have to execute the following line after \maketitle:
         \sbox0{$ $} \scriptfont1=\scriptfont0

If you need to execute your lines after \begin{document} you write:
         \AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$ $} \scriptfont1=\scriptfont0}

I was searching for something like \AfterMakeTitle which does the same thing as \AtBeginDocument

Comment: It's not clear what `\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0` would be useful for.

Comment: It's a command to change the default font for subscript or superscript in math mode. Due to the document class, I have to use I must type these commands after \maketitle

Comment: It ***doesn't*** work. See my answer to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a command/macro `\myMacro` that you want to execute immediately after `\maketitle` has been executed, you could use the following approach to automate this:

```
% Save original \maketitle definition
\let\myMakeTitle\maketitle
% Redefine \maketitle to execute \myMacro after the original \maketitle is done
\def\makeTitle{\myMakeTitle \myMacro}
```

Whether it really is a good idea to redefine `\maketitle`, I don't know. Maybe it would be better to provide a custom title-creation macro for your package so users can opt-in to using your version of creating a title (aka: executing your macro after `\maketitle`)

Comment: I thought about this solution, I was looking for a much more general command in order to use it inside my package if an option has passed. I will try this in the following days.

Answer (score 2):

With an up-to-date LaTeX, you can do

```
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{<whatever code you want>}
```

However, I warn you from doing `\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0`.

My hunch is that your *cuggino*<sup>1</sup> gave you a wonderful receipt to make subscripts in the upright font instead of having to type

```
$x_{\mathrm{eff}}$
```

and using the easier

```
$x_{eff}$
```

You were also told that, for mysterious reasons, the magic `\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0` has to be issued after `\maketitle`, but that the magic has to be prefixed by the esoteric `\sbox0{$ $}`.

Unfortunately, this fails in several ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\author{Lorenzo\thanks{Supported by Topo Gigio}}
\title{Good looking title}
\maketitle

% Let's assume you want to do this
\sbox0{$ $}
\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0

This formula looks funny: $x_{\alpha}+x_{eff}$ (scriptfont1 is \fontname\scriptfont1)

\section{More about $x$}

The formula is funny in a different way: $x_{\alpha}+x_{eff}$ (scriptfont1 is \fontname\scriptfont1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you see the problem? In the first formula, you get upright font for “eff”, but the `\alpha` command outputs a very wrong character.

But in the second formula the `\alpha` is correct and “eff” is in math italic.

Why? Because LaTeX, at each formula in a different size, recalculates `\textfont`, `\scriptfont` and `\scriptscriptfont`. Since a formula is typeset in the section title, the recalculation is performed and another is done for the formula at the normal size, so your cousin's cunning trick fails miserably.

A better way would be to use `x_|eff|` instead, with a suitable definition of `|`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\math@active@bar}{}
\def\math@active@bar#1|{{\mathrm{#1}}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`| \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\math@active@bar
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`|="8000 }
\makeaother

\begin{document}

$x_{\alpha}+x_|eff|$

\end{document}
```

If you need the absolute value, use `\lvert...\rvert`. Or you may use `!` instead of `|` (if you don't need factorials).

[image]

---

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup> In Italy it's frequent to say “mio cuggino mi ha detto” (my cousin told me, but with wrong orthography for “cugino”) in reference with fake news. Thus the OP can blame someone else.

Comment: The solution with | is a really interesting. Would you mind adding some comments to explain the different commands? Especially the two lines before `\makeaother`. I am also somewhat puzzled by the need to both `newcommand` and `def` the same `\math@active@bar`.

Comment: @Tohiko There's plenty of examples of codes like that on the site. The last line tells LaTeX to consider `|` math active (so in math it behaves like a macro). The line above defines a meaning for the active `|` (without the need to make it active). A mostly equivalent way would be ``\catcode`|=\active\let|=\math@active@bar\catcode`=12``

Comment: I use those commands to change the font for sup and sub text in math globally, to avoid type \rm or \mathrm every time.
\sbox0{$ $} Is used to initialize the math environment,
\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0 is used to change the font.
Your example works because I don't want to change greek letters.

Comment: However, I tried with: \AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{<commands>} and the it works even inside a package.

Comment: @LorenzoLunghini As I showed in my answer, you *are* changing Greek letters in subscripts in (almost) unpredictable ways and the method doesn't generally work.

Comment: @egreg you're right, I was trying your example and the script with '|' is useful, is there a way to change |<expression>| to {<expression}>?

Comment: @LorenzoLunghini No, unless you want to change the meaning of `_` and be prepared to suffer pain. You really don't want to have all subscripts in upright type, do you?

Comment: @egreg I would like to be able to change the meaning of _ robustly, but I think that I will use | instead of _ or ^.